# Manipulating jQuery draggables/droppables in script [UPD]

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, droppable

I want to append item to sortable list by script. Users can drag item to list directly, and can check some checkboxes and press "Send to list" button. First approach works, second is not.

The problem is if I pass $(ui.draggable) to function, it works. But if i point to draggable element by jQuery chain (`$(this).parent().parent().find('div.drag')`) and pass this, it won't work. It seems that these two objects are not equal (i tried cloning second object and reducing it to one with `eq`, and nothing works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i got it :) Problem was in `move_to_list` function.